# Query for desired output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which is given below ,

[image]

write a `SQL` query for Output like this below irrespective of Id field but in **gender** field having alternate 'M' and 'F'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interleave the values in by using `order by` with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by gender order by id),
         gender desc;
```

The `row_number()` interleaves the values.  The `gender desc` puts `'M'` first.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your answer ,but that is not working for me.

Comment: @AjeetVerma . . . If the problem was a syntax error, then I removed the offending comma.